# Non-continuous data issue Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am loading around 14 days of data using highcharts js, there is a problem in the X-axis whenever the dataset loaded with respect to dropdowns is having non-continuous data (i.e for day 1, 2, 3 there is data for 4,5,6 no data for 7,8,9 data present and so on )

For this scenario, the output is showing wrong values in x-axis and are correct only in tool tip.

Also like in the example above the data for days 7,8,9 will show on 4,5,6 on x-axis but show 7,8,9 on the tool tip.

Example 2: Data for 15th july(tooltip) shown in 13th july (x-axis)
[image]

However, in another tab this does not happen and for non-continuous data also everything is shown properly, for missing data, 0 value is shown there and continued thereafter.
I have checked and rechecked the codes and they are exactly the same. Is this a bug ? I don't understand why this is happening.

Code snippets:

```
xAxis: {
            type : 'datetime',
            min : Date.UTC(new Date(processed_json[0][0]).getYear(),new Date(processed_json[0][0]).getMonth(),new Date(processed_json[0][0]).getDate()),
            max : Date.UTC(new Date(processed_json[processed_json.length - 1][0]).getYear(),new Date(processed_json[processed_json.length - 1][0]).getMonth(),new Date(processed_json[processed_json.length - 1][0]).getDate()) 
}
```

All approaches/suggestions are most welcome

Comment: Can you replicate our example as live demo with hardcoded data which introduce us your issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861690/discontinuous-dataset-in-highcharts

Can you check this question, please? I have explained the problem clearly here.